# Why does this readable stream event, "data", output behave this way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

Why does the output of this code snippet behave this way?
I expected 1 'true' string and 2 'false' strings to be printed, I got one 'false' only instead?

Thank you for your time.

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8')
process.stdin.on('data', (input) => console.log(input==="1"));
```

/* STDIN:
1
2
3
*/

/* STDOUT:
false
*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `input` is `"1 2 3\n"`. `data` contains as much input as is available to be read. (In the case of standard console I/O, that will often be a line.) There's nothing about the stream that attempts to tokenize it by breaking it at spaces or anything like that.